# AWS Spark EMR Numpy Import Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, numpy, pyspark, emr

I'm trying to submit a Python script on AWS EMR that imports numpy but I get

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I tried using one of the answers here: [No module named numpy when spark-submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449271/no-module-named-numpy-when-spark-submitting).
I created a bootstrap_actions.sh script that includes

```
 sudo yum install python-numpy python-scipy -y
```

and I run the script when I create the cluster but still get the import error. Any solution on how can I get import numpy to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Amazon EMR you need to use bootstrap actions. Installing from the console only changes the master node and not the task nodes.

```
runners:
  emr:
    bootstrap:
    - sudo yum install -y python27-numpy
```

I am assuming that you will be using Python 2.7. If you are using Python 3.x, the link below has examples installing with PIP in the bootstrap. I am also assuming that you are using a recent EMR AMI.

[EMR Bootstrapping Cookbook](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/emr-bootstrap-cookbook.html)

Comment: It works! I just changed my bootstrap script to include the line you had: sudo yum install -y python27-numpy - Thanks!